# Update database automatically

Tags: database, triggers, jobs

I want my database to automatically update my auction status to "closed" when auction end date has expired. At the same time I need the product (who had been in status "auction") turn back to status " normal". What would be the best method? I tarief different things , but need your professional opinion.

Comment: What RDBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle,...) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of database you use. Such "business logic" is usually done in the application.

At the database level you can however achieve this by having **views** that you always read from. This way you move the business logic in the database, but can simulate whatever conditions you want. E.g. the view will return "closed" if that end_date is smaller than actual date (sysdate for Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MS SQL Server (standard or higher):

You can use SQL Server Agent to schedule a SQL command (otherwise use sqlcmd icm a scheduler).

Then call a stored procedure which executes these update queries for you.

If you want to prevent too much polling on the database, you can also retrieve the next timeout moment for any item, and only execute the (remainder of) the stored procedure when it that time has passed.